# __debuginfo error with Xdebug and CakePHP 4

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, cakephp, xdebug, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to use XDebug on VSCode to debug a PHP 8.1 / CakePHP 4.3 project hosted on a local Docker container, but it always fails with this error:

```
2022-05-25 12:11:36 error: [Cake\Error\FatalErrorException] __debuginfo() must return an array in /var/www/repo/public/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/BehaviorRegistry.php on line 78
Stack Trace:
- /var/www/repo/public/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php:119
- [main] - [internal], line ??
```

This is my `launch.json` config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pathMappings": {
              "/var/www/repo": "<path/to/my/local/project>"
             }
        },
   ]
}
```

If I set `"stopOnEntry": true`, XDebug correctly stops at the first line of the entrypoint of my project (I.E. the `webroot/index.php` file), but when I get to the `$server->emit($server->run());` line, I get the error.

Same if I set `"stopOnEntry": false`, and set a breakpoint somewhere in my project (I.E. `Application.php` or `Controller/AppController.php`). No matter where I put the breakpoint, I always get the same error about `__debuginfo()`.

What's going on here? Is CakePHP somehow incompatible with XDebug, because internally the framework is using the `__debuginfo()` incorrectly? Or does CakePHP 4 actually work with XDebug, and I'm doing something wrong in my own code (though I can't understand what or where) and the error is just cryptic? Does anybody have any experience with getting XDebug to work on a CakePHP 4 project correctly?

Comment: What's on line 78 of /var/www/repo/public/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/BehaviorRegistry.php ?

Comment: @LajosArpad a method signature... which makes no sense at all to me. `public function setTable(Table $table): void`

Comment: What happens if you change that to `public function setTable(Table $table): []`?

Comment: @LajosArpad I can't change it, it's not my code, as you can see it's a method from CakePHP's codebase that resides inside the `vendor` folder.

Comment: Technically you can. The question aimed to suggest a temporary change to find out what the problem is, it is not meant to be a long-term change.

Comment: @LajosArpad I tried changing the file and I get the same error.

Comment: Do you have a call of `__debuginfo` inside the `setTable method?

Comment: Generally CakePHP works mostly just fine with Xdebug (just tested with PHP 8.1.6, Xdebug 3.1.4, and CakePHP 4.3.9). If you look at [**the source code**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.3.9/src/Core/ObjectRegistry.php#L410-L418), `__debugInfo()` should actually return an array. Maybe you are triggering a weird edge case / bug. I would suggest to open an issue over at GitHub with a way to reproduce the problem with a fresh CakePHP app installation.

Answer (score 2):

> because internally the framework is using the __debuginfo incorrectly

Yes, that is likely it.

`__debugInfo()` must return an array.

Xdebug invokes `__debugInfo()` to obtain information information for some variables. If during the normal execution of a script this is never done, then the error will not show up, but because Xdebug does use it, you will run into this. I would suggest you report this to the Cake people as it is only something they can fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your PHP version is 8.1.x and the CakePHP version that you use assumes an older PHP version which was more lenient with type enforcing of the types. You have several options:

- you can downgrade to an older version of PHP
- you can fix the code in CakePHP for the time being
- you can send an error report to CakePHP

With PHP 8.1.x the `: sometype` specifications are enforced and they were not enforced previously.